# don't getting single question details from google form api

Tags: javascript, rest, google-api, google-docs, google-forms

I'm trying to get single question details from google form api but getting 404 error:

```
GET https://forms.googleapis.com/v1/forms/${id}/questions/${questionId}
Authorization: Bearer ${token}
```

but returning this 404:

```
404. That’s an error.  The requested URL /v1/forms/12iy9KabJ6fE4xKhehIsWgsJgCbhqFZzntRJEP_siyX8/questions/0000000e was not found on this server
```

I hope I get response of this question details and validation details.